# HTML5 & CSS3: How can I make sure that my code is compatible to all browsers?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I am working with webdesign every browsers shows something different which ruins the layout. Is there any tools or guidelines to make a webdesign without any problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Understand and embrace the fact that a screen is not the same as a piece of paper, and that the "perfect web layout" isn't the same as a fixed printed paper layout. You can only imitate foreign technology so long. At some point your car has to stop looking like a horse carriage and more like a Porsche.

Comment: You'll have to specify what you meant by "perfect webdesign". What goals do you want to achieve that you want tools and guidelines for?

Comment: You can't be 100% sure. This will be true as long as browsers keep releasing new versions. One very important tip: [validate your HTML and CSS](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: @Madmartigan: There's not much of a point in trying to validate HTML5 or CSS3 right now, though :/

Comment: @BoltClock: That's untrue. If you actually read the errors, you can decide what's version related and what is simply a mistake, like mismatched tags, malformed attributes, or duplicate ids. There is also the unofficial HTML5 validator: http://html5.validator.nu/ I think it should be stressed because I believe validation errors (specifically HTML) are the #1 cause of cross-browser issues and layout problems in general. Yes there are a host of CSS issues, but you need a solid foundation first before you can tackle those.

Comment: The Nu validator seems pretty good for HTML5, but the Jigsaw validator hasn't quite caught up with CSS3 yet. And as much as you stress it, who actually reads errors?

Comment: @BoltClock: People who are looking for them I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different tools and technologies that can help make this better/easier but nothing beats good old cross-browser testing. Here are some tools you might like:

- http://browsershots.org/
- http://spoon.net/Browsers/
- http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that all designs must look the same in all browsers. It's nearly impossible with the growing range of browsers and devices that must be supported, but I understand that things shouldn't break.

This might require a case-to-case basis, but some things to look into are:

1. Use HTML5 Shiv so IE browsers can recognize HTML5 elements: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/
2. You could also look into HTML5 Boilerplate but that could be overkill http://html5boilerplate.com/
3. In the design process, make sure any CSS3 properties are not so critical to design that they break it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to tweak the design for each specific type of browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CSS framework such as http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ or http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/ can certainly help in that process.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) (here is [another one](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)) or some [HTML boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) you can, at least reduce most of the oddities with different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Grab Modernizr for a start, which uses **selectivizr** I believe!

For Li's I would use

```
li{
  display: inline-block; //NO Floats
  *display: inline; /* < target IE7 */
  *zoom:1;
}
```

Double margins: fix those with IE conditional stylesheet OR html5boilerplate

Most other elements would depend on `display` type

**For CSS3** maybe use [CSSPie](http://css3pie.com/)

**Clears:**

```
:after{
    content: '.';
    clear:both;
    visibility: hidden;
    *zoom:1;
    height:0;
    display:block;
 }
```

Some of the other issue's are fixed quite easily!

For screen width's use % instead of PX for greater control